# Is it possible to acheive this in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to implement the following in google sheets, but I don't know how to or if it is even possible

I have a sheet, let's call it "products", in which every entry has an ID tag and a value

I want to have another sheet, call it "orders" with the following two columns: "products ID" and "sum"

I want to put multiple IDs in the "products ID" column, and have the "sum" column sum the values of all entries in the sheet "products" that match the product IDs listed.

Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the link to a test sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?  If not, then refine your question.

[image]

The VLOOKUP uses the ID tag on orders to find the corresponding value. 
D3 is the tag being looked up.  A$3:B$13 is where to look.  Vlookup checks the first column to find the value.  2 says return the second column. 0 says the list isn't sorted.

Bottom blue tint box is the sum.

This should probably be extended:  Products tab should have another column with the description of the item.  This will help catch ID typos, and help reconcile the bill later.

Orders tab probably needs a count and an extension column and a description column.  The description is retrieved the same way.

Products tab now looks like this:
[image]

But when we copy the formula down in orders...

[image]

Thos #N/A's are a nuisance.  There's two solutions:

- Put an entry "-" in the Products page, and fill unused ID tags in Orders with - also.  VLookup checks - and returns blank.

The other way is to wrap the vlookup in an iferror

=iferror(vlookup(E4,A$3:C$13,2,0),"") which says, 'run the following formula, and if it barfs, leave the cell empty'